# Pass data to a running AsyncTask

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android application.

I want to test how asynchronous sockets work on Android doing a simple echo client.

On [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) I have found the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    public class EchoClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Socket echoSocket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
                out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                            echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                                   + "the connection to: taranis.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                       new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;

        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
        }
    }
```

Instead of reading form `System.in` I want to let users fill an EditText and when user tap on a button I want to send the text introduced by user on that EditText.

And also, I want to make it using an AsyncTask. The above code will be on `AsyncTask.doBackground()` method.

I want to do the following: a user introduces a text, then he taps on send button, then he waits to see the response. When I get the response from Echo Server I let the user to introduces a new text and the process start over. There is another button to close socket and end the program.

My problem is: how can I notify that there is text available to send? In other words, when user taps over the send button, what must I do to pass that text to AsyncTask?

Comment: The simplest solution is just create a second AsyncTask and start running it when user taps over the second button. In another word, each button click will trigger a new AsyncTask to run: `new MyAsyncTask().execute(userInput);`

Comment: @yorkw and how can I send back data from the `AsynkTask`, and catch it from the main activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` essentially lets you do the following things:

- Start the task with some parameters
- Handles background threading for you in a simple way (you don't have to worry about it)
- Lets you publish results to the UI thread in a systematic way.

In your case, it sounds like you're not sending data *to* the task, but rather, you're *starting* the task with a specified parameter.

If you look at the examples given in the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you will see that the first parameter of the template definition is the set of parameters to start the task.  In your case, you would probably want to use a `URL` (or possibly simply String) parameter.  When the user clicks the button, you start the task, download the stuff, and then publish the results to the UI thread!

Comment: Probably, I haven't explained well. I want to do the following: a user introduces a text, then he taps on send button, then he waits to see the response. When I get the response from Echo Server I let the user to introduces a new text and the process start over. There is another button to close socket and end the program.

Comment: If you have a background thread that's constantly talking to the server, then that's not really what AsyncTask is meant for.  That's pretty heavyweight, and instead I'd look at using a Service with a custom Messenger/Handler combo which talks to the server and puts data on the UI via messages.  (This is typical practice in chat apps, btw.)

Comment: AsyncTasks are meant for _tasks_, by comparison, this isn't an atomic task, but something that sits in the background constantly (or at least, fairly) and talks to the user by connecting with an Activity, which is the case in point example of a service.

Comment: I'm using a service but know I don't know how to pass text to local service. How can I pass text to send through open socket? May I need to call startService() method?

Comment: Using startService() and a socket are at odds with each other, it's one or the other, and neither makes much sense.  To communicate, you will use a Messenger / Handler combo, where the Activity "binds" to the Service, and then they can pass messages back and forth. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

Comment: My service is a local service: can I use Messenger with a Local Service?

Comment: So, how can I send the result data from the `AsyncTask`, to the activity that make the `.execute();` ?, I think it must be in `onPostExecute`, but how ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are building a chat application.

- **To send text** to the server, you can start a new `AsyncTask` every time the user clicks on the "Send" button. But make sure that you are stopping those tasks after you complete your operation.
- **To receive replies**, you can start a `Service` and check your server regularly. Whenever you get a new message to display, you can send a broadcast to the main activity. And, inside the activity you need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` object which listens to the broadcasts from the `Service`.

So, when your `BroadcastReceiver` receives a new broadcast from the `Service`, update the messages list with your message/text.